# Unable to render component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've tried to render a simple component but cant seem to make it work.

```
<Col md={{ span: 16, offset: 4 }} xs={{ span: 20, offset: 2 }}>
    {props.language === "en" ? <englishReport /> : <danishReport />}
</Col>
```

This is what `<englishReport/>` component and `<danishReport/>` looks like

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class indexDanish extends Component {
    render() { 
        return ( 
             <div style={{ color: "#fff", textAlign: "left" }}>
                 <b>hej</b>
             </div>
         );
    }
}

export default indexDanish;
```

I have imported both components in the parent component

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A custom component name needs to start with a capital letter, [or Babel will treat that as a string](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=DwUwdg5gNglgzgCwEogA4HsBOAXABAegD4g&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4).

Change the `englishReport` and `danishReport` names to `EnglishReport` and `DanishReport` and it will work.

```
<Col md={{ span: 16, offset: 4 }} xs={{ span: 20, offset: 2 }}>
  {props.language === "en" ? <EnglishReport /> : <DanishReport />}
</Col>
```